# How to install windows xp and Redhat Linux in one hard disk drive

Tags: windows-xp, multi-boot, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have 500 GB Hard disk drive and I created 5 partition c,d,e,f,g. I installed windows xp on c drive and I stored some important file, games on d,e,f. My g (20 GB free Space) partition is totally empty. So I want to install Rad hat linux on g partition without loss my file and window. Is it possible, Please, Help me to give this question answer.

Comment: -1 "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: Wait, why did you create 5 partitions on a single drive for a Windows install?  That's how many partitions I have for a dual boot by itself, and that assumes I don't have a second drive for shared files.  Two, maybe three for most users.

Comment: Indeed, splitting your Windows over 4 partitions is only going to give you a performance impact without any gain at all. You should reconsider having only two partitions as an end result...

Answer (score 2):

### Backups!

Most importantly, make a backup of all important data onto a separate device and check that it actually contains everything of importance to you. Disconnect it and put it somewhere safe!

### Reading The Friendly Manual

The [Red Hat Linux Installation Guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/index.html) is a good place to start. The relevant section is [Disk Partitioning](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-diskpartsetup-x86.html)

You should probably select [create custom layout](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-diskpartitioning-x86.html) where you can create or delete partions as needed. Note that Linux will assign different names to partitions (it won't be called G) so be careful to select the correct partition. Read the manual carefully and note anything it says about the need for a [swap partition](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-swapspace.html).

> If you chose to create a custom layout, you must tell the installation program where to install Red Hat Enterprise Linux. This is done by defining mount points for one or more disk partitions in which Red Hat Enterprise Linux is installed. You may also need to create and/or delete partitions at this time.

### RHEL/Fedora/centOS/Ubuntu

As you know, RHEL is available by paying an annual subscription and targeted at large corporate businesses. Many people who want to learn about RHEL at home use CentOS instead.

If you are new to Linux I suggest you consider using something like Ubuntu.